# My files are showing .blower file extension

Tags: windows-7, file-extension, virus-removal, malware-removal, system-file

My files are showing .blower file extension. I have tried to remove malware and viruses but this problem is still there. Installed Microsoft Security Essentials and also ran Microsoft Malicious Software Removal Tool. Now the system is not showing any viruses but file extensions are changed how to recover or decrypt those files.

[image: encrypted files]
[image: read_me note]

Answer (score 0):

The Damage is done, if you do not have backups of important files stored somewhere else you may be out of luck.

The files are encrypted and cannot be easily un-encrypted depending on the version of ransomware that encrypted them if they can ever be un-encrypted

In the link below scroll about halfway down for some utilities that may un-encrypt the blower files..

[Link](http://www.myantispyware.com/2019/02/04/blower-file-extension-ransomware-restore-blower-files/)

If they can be recovered copy them to and external drive and unplug the drive from the pc, you can never be sure you have removed the ransomware so it is best to do a clean Install of the Operating System to be sure.

Comment: Link is not working.

Comment: What if I Restore the System to a previous point. Will it work for this problem?

Comment: No, that will not work.

Comment: Is there any way to decrypt these files.

Comment: Link is fixed, please read about half way down on the page for possibilities for decryption